# jQuery my script is overridden

Tags: jquery

[link to page exhibiting problem](http://www.thdyoung.com/gopag/index.php/cu_projects/projectsp)

hi, 
My jq script, assembled from tuts on the web, is being overridden by the main tabbing jQ and its associated styling. This is the part of my script that is being overridden `$(reff2+' li:first').addClass('ui-tabs-selected');` The rest of the script below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#propagin a").live('click', function(eve) {
        eve.preventDefault();

        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        var reff = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*?(\d+)\/.*$/g, "$1");
        var reff2 = '#fragment-' + reff ;

        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(html) {
                $(reff2).html(html);
            }
        });

        $(reff2 + ' li:first').addClass('ui-tabs-selected');
    });
});
```

The behaviour I want is that the first sub-tab should be selected or in other words have the correct class assigned to it by my jq script. Clicking the pagination links brings into view the right set of new sub-tabs which means that the ajax part of my script is working. But the first sub-tab of the new set doesn't have the right class e.g ui-tabs-selected.

You can see the process unfolding in the browser. The new set of sub-tabs appears on clicking the pagination links, and for a moment the first sub-tab is correctly styled, before the more senior tabbing jq with its styling kicks in and removes the style that I want.

What can I do about this that doesn't clobber the senior jquery and its associated CSS which together make possible the slightly convoluted tabbing scheme that I have ?

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of the code in the page you provided is still linking to localhost.

```
    <link type="text/css" href="http://localhost/gopag//css/ui.tabs.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link type="text/css" href="http://localhost/gopag//css/nested-jquery-yui.css"  rel="stylesheet">
```

Once those are fixed, then it'll be easier to see what the issues might be.

You may also want to fix the `#propagin` div - having three divs with the same ID can cause unpredictable behaviour (each element should have a unique id). You can either change the div to a class (and update your CSS/jQuery to `.propagin`), or have ids like `#propagin1`, `#propagin2` etc.

EDIT:

Hi Tom,
Sorry I wasn't able to get back to you right away. I scraped a copy of your website and found the same issue you had, until I moved the `addClass` inside the `$.ajax` function. The style applied properly after that:

```
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",   
    success: function(html){
        $(reff2).html(html);
        $(reff2 + ' li:first').addClass('ui-tabs-selected');
    }
});
```

Hopefully, that works for you.

Comment: Apologies for the localhost silliness. I have corrected it. Regards the div 'propagin', is your opinion that this explains the jQuery problem that I've experienced ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think so. I can't tell exactly what you're trying to achieve, since your code is correctly applying the `$(reff2 + ' li:first').addClass('ui-tabs-selected')` on click. However, the script `ui.tabs.min.js` already applies that style to those `li`s when your page loads. So, of course, when you click on it, you don't see any change because the style is already there.

Comment: Hmm, now I see what you're saying. I think something may be up with your HTML, since when I save your page locally, it works as you want it. You may want to take the extra slash out of your JS and CSS includes - `http://www.thdyoung.com/gopag//js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js` should be `http://www.thdyoung.com/gopag/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js`

Comment: ui.tabs.min.js is boss js: just looking at it gives me palpitations. Joking aside, my goal is to ensure that pages reached via the pagination links display the first sub-tab correctly. That's done by addClass('ui-tabs-selected') which sticks for a microsecond before being overridden. Effectively, I'm asking for a tweak. I don't know if that tweak is to the heavy-duty jquery or my own script.

Comment: Tom, have a look at http://bjornthomson.com/testtabs/index.html. I've just copied your html into a file on my server, and it works as I think you wanted. Does it look right? If so, I'm sure we can fix the issue.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that helps you much, sorry, particularly as the ajax calls won't do anything on my server. I do have some suggestions - if you want, I'd be happy to talk about them in a Stack Overflow chat.

Comment: @g_thom let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1987/discussion-between-tom-and-g-thom)